# How to get a single value in API

Tags: php, api

How will i be able to get a single value out of BTC-e API using PHP?. This is the current API that i can use.

https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd

As you can see, it shows lots of information, but i dont need many information that is displayed there. What can i do so that i will only get

```
"last":284.323
```

this number?

Thank you for your help regarding this subject.

Comment: json_decode() it and extract the element that you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the received data is a JSON value.

If you simply want to receive data from a website, you can use the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

With the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, you can create an object from this data.

If you're looking for a specific value, you maybe can use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to get a clarifying list of the given data.

When you use the print_r function on the given data, it will return:

`stdClass Object
(
    [btc_usd] => stdClass Object
        (
            [high] => 288.957
            [low] => 272.00201
            [avg] => 280.479505
            [vol] => 2178508.65397
            [vol_cur] => 7771.83325
            [last] => 286.322
            [buy] => 286.328
            [sell] => 286.322
            [updated] => 1445787588
        )
)`

As you can see, you are looking for a variable stored in `->btc_usd->last`

So when it all comes together, you can use the following:

```
<?php
# Get String
$_ApiString = '{"btc_usd":{"high":288.957,"low":272.00201,"avg":280.479505,"vol":2178508.65397,"vol_cur":7771.83325,"last":286.322,"buy":286.328,"sell":286.322,"updated":1445787588}}';

# Or maybe you simply want to download it from a website
$_ApiString = file_get_contents('https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd');

# Create object from ApiString
$_Object    = json_decode($_ApiString);

# Get variable
$_Last      = $_Object->btc_usd->last;
?>
```

Comment: My god, everything explained in detail. Thank you very much for all of your help inputed in answering my question.

BUT something else, how do i put the link in APISTRING, so the information is always fresh?
Do i just put the link in apistring?

Comment: In a simple use like this, you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the data.